# drop rows with errors for pandas data coercion

Tags: python, pandas, coercion

I have a dataframe, for which I need to convert columns to floats and ints, that has bad rows, ie., values that are in a column that should be a float or an integer are instead string values.

If I use `df.bad.astype(float)`, I get an error, this is expected.

If I use `df.bad.astype(float, errors='coerce')`, or `pd.to_numeric(df.bad, errors='coerce')`, bad values are replaced with `np.NaN`, also according to spec and reasonable.

There is also `errors='ignore'`, another option that ignores the errors and leaves the erroring values alone.

But actually, I want to not ignore the errors, but drop the rows with bad values. How can I do this?

I can ignore the errors and do some type checking, but that's not an ideal solution, and there might be something more idiomatic to do this.

#### Example

```
test = pd.DataFrame(["3", "4", "problem"], columns=["bad"])
test.bad.astype(float) ## ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'problem'
```

I want something like this:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.bad, errors='drop')
```

And this returns dataframe with only the 2 good rows.

Comment: Could you post a small example along with your expected output?!

Comment: are you after `pd.to_numeric(test.bad, errors='coerce').dropna()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the bad values are replaced with `np.NaN` would it not be simply just `df.dropna()` to get rid of the bad rows now?

EDIT:
Since you need to not drop the initial NaNs, maybe you could use `df.fillna()` prior to using `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: Yes, this might be part of the solution, but if there are missing values in the column already, then those are dropped as well.